# Перенаправление сайта не на доменное имя а по url кнопки

Tags: django

Такая проблема. Я подключила сайт джанго к хостингу, но есть одна проблема. На сайте имеется к нопка с url адресом
return HttpResponseRedirect('http://metrika.yandex.ru/promo?),')

Я ввожу домен, а он вместо сайта переходит по ссылке url адреса кнопки. Как я могу это исправить